# I installed DKIM and SPF. Do I need to install Domain Keys as well?

Tags: domainkeys

I have linux apache mysql and php server.  My website uses the php mail() function and the server's postfix server to email other people.

I successfully installed SPF and DKIM on my server to reduce the likelihood of my website's email-outs from ending up in people's spam boxes.

In my research, I stumbled on [Domain Keys](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DomainKeys) which seems to be a "historical" version of DKIM.  Do the big web mail services like Google, Yahoo and Hotmail still use Domain Keys?  If not, then maybe I don't need to install it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DKIM is sufficient and includes Domain Keys as part of its specification.  If you're running DKIM and signing outgoing mail, you're in a good position.

Answer (score 0):

Wrong, DKIM and DomainKeys are different. Yahoo uses Domainkeys so I recommend to install it. Find instructions here [Postfix with DKIM, Domainkeys, SPf and Sender-ID](http://www.tai.ro/2010/04/03/postfix-with-dkim-domainkeys-spf-and-sender-id/)